# ExtJS: Put size/margin/padding in Component or External .css File?`

Tags: extjs

Is there a 'best practice' when it comes to specifying size/margin/padding info in components (i.e., adding it programmattically via JavaScript) vs. putting it in external CSS files?

I've gotten into the habit of doing the former. But I can see some people arguing for putting that stuff in an external CSS file so that you could, in theory, modify layouts (size/margin/padding) in different themes.

What do others think? Is there an established best practice?

Thanks.

Comment: After doing some add'l research, it appears that one nice perk to putting size/padding info in your ExtJS code (instead of CSS files) is that ExtJS handles cross-browser box sizing differences for you. For example, if you specify that a panel should be X pixels wide, ExtJS will ensure it's the same size in both Firefox and IE "quirks" mode. For more info scroll down to the "Browser Compatibility Issue" section here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach I find is to assign classes to all your components and style them in your CSS files. For example...

```
var styledPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    cls: 'panel-styled',
    items: [ ]
});
```

And then have a CSS rule to style it...

```
.styled-panel {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Obviously, this allows you to group component styles together as well.

As a side note, I usually use the `bodyStyle` property to add formatting which isn't likely to change, for example... most Windows need padding and this isn't likely to change frequently so I stick that in the `bodyStyle` property.

```
var paddedWindow = new Ext.Window({
    title: 'Window',
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 4px;'
});
```